# Python curses unsets 'onlcr' and breaks my terminal; how to reset *properly*

Tags: python, terminal, curses, stty

I have the following basic curses implementation in Python3.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import curses
import time
from curses import wrapper

stdscr = curses.initscr() # required

curses.noecho() # don't show keyboard input
curses.cbreak() # don't require enter to send input

stdscr.keypad(True)

def main(stdscr):
   # curses.newwin(5, 10, 7, 20)
   stdscr.addstr("SUMMON SHOGGOTHS")
   stdscr.addstr(20, 30, "Razzmatazz")
   stdscr.refresh()
   time.sleep(3)



wrapper(main)

# Unwind
curses.nocbreak()
stdscr.keypad(False)
curses.echo()
curses.endwin()
```

Pretty much everything happens that I would expect: Shoggoths are Summoned and Razzes are matazzed, *however* when I enter `git status` my lines breaks are broken.

Doing a diff between `stty -a` before and after showed:

```
5c5
< iflags: -istrip icrnl -inlcr -igncr ixon -ixoff ixany imaxbel -iutf8
---
> iflags: -istrip -icrnl -inlcr -igncr ixon -ixoff ixany imaxbel -iutf8
7c7
< oflags: opost onlcr -oxtabs -onocr -onlret
---
> oflags: opost -onlcr -oxtabs -onocr -onlret
```

After investigating these options, I found that issuing `stty onlcr` fixes the terminal. I'm surprised, however, because I thought that [`curses.endwin()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.endwin) would have reset me:

> De-initialize the library, and return terminal to normal status.

I thought it might be an issue in iTerm2, so then I tried with Terminal.app. This produced the same behavior.

I'm stumped is there some other re-set technique? I saw in C-based implementations the stty data are often saved into a struct for restoration...that might be an avenue of pursuit.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The likely problem is this (see [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/curses/wrapper.py)):

- the curses [**`wrapper`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.wrapper) method does an `initscr` and `endwin`.
- when your script exits from **`wrapper`**, the curses library is back in *shell mode*
- changing **`curses.nocbreak()`** is redundant, and may be causing the curses library's *current* terminal modes to be updated from the *program mode*
- calling **`endwin`** updates the wrong settings.

I'd simply delete the chunk marked "# Unwind".